# Make Zend Search Lucene more "sensitive"

Tags: php, zend-framework, search, lucene

I was wondering if someone knows what I need to do to make Zend Search more sensitive. Currently, say I am searching for the word:

```
Penelope
```

from my index, I need to type in the entire word in order to get a match. What I'm after is that when I type 'P' it immediately returns relevant results for content having words beginning with 'P'.

I am using the standard

```
$index->find('Penelope');
```

Do I need to use the query builder to achieve this, or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the lucene documentation, you can use wildcards. `?` for single character wildcards, and `*` for multicharacter wildcards. try something like this.

```
$index->find('Pe*');
```

More info here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.query-language.html

If this is what you are looking for, please select the check mark next to this answer. Thanks!